# Kivy: UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u017c' in position 256: illegal multibyte sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I wanted to try coding GUI so I installed Kivy, but from this part of the code:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
```

I got an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u017c' in position 256: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Does someone know how to fix it?